# Return a file location from a switch-statement

Tags: c#, scope, switch-statement

I'm pretty new to programming but I'm trying to have my method return a value that contains a file location which is dependent on a users desired choice. 
I've been fiddling with this for over a day now and am stuck on how to return the value correctly, I keep it keeps telling me not all code paths return a value. 
How do I fix this and have the code path be returned to the main

```
public static string fileLocation()
    {
        int fileRequest = 10;
        bool errorCheck = true;
        string filePath;

        while (errorCheck == true)
        {
            Console.Write(">Enter '1' through '9' to choose a hand.");
            Console.Write("Enter '0' for random.");
            fileRequest = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (fileRequest)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Random selection loading.");
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    fileRequest = rnd.Next(10);
                    errorCheck = true;
                    return (null);

                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file one.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("Flush.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file two.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("FourKind.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file three.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("FullHouse.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file four.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("Pair.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file five.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("RoyalFlush.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file six.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("Straight.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file seven.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("StraightFlush.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 8:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file eight.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("ThreeKind.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                case 9:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Loading file nine.");
                    filePath = Path.GetFullPath("TwoPair.txt");
                    errorCheck = false;
                    return (Convert.ToString(filePath));

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(">Invalid request.");
                    filePath = "Invalid";
                    errorCheck = true;
                    return (null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your code doing that you expect it to behave differently? Have you learned to use your IDE's debugger and step through the code line by line as it executes?

Comment: what's your problem??? you did not asked nothing...

Comment: You set error check to true and then have a loop that only runs if it's false. Therefore your loop and switch statement never execute

Comment: Read your code more carefully. `bool errorCheck = true; while (errorCheck != true)` means your loop can never execute. (And you can simplify the test with `while (!errorCheck)`, btw.)

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Take something for your headache, wait for it to work, and then try your code again and post your question.

Comment: Why do you use a while loop? The loop is just executed once and it  returns.

Comment: One possible reason for downvotes - you could have modified sample to be much smaller - there is no reason for Console.Write calls, multiple `case` options... Calling `Convert.ToString` on string value is really unnecessary, but would not cause downvote (could probably be upvoted in the past when joke questions/answers were more accepted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming what you're trying to do is take an integer between 0 and 9 as input. If it's 0, you want to treat it randomly as 1 through 9. If it's anything else, you want to ask for input again. This should do it (untested):

```
public static string FileLocation()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(">Enter '1' through '9' to choose a hand.");
        Console.Write("Enter '0' for random.");
        int fileRequest = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        if (fileRequest == 0)
            fileRequest = (new Random()).Next(1, 10);

        switch (fileRequest)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file one.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("Flush.txt");

            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file two.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("FourKind.txt");

            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file three.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("FullHouse.txt");

            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file four.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("Pair.txt");

            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file five.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("RoyalFlush.txt");

            case 6:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file six.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("Straight.txt");

            case 7:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file seven.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("StraightFlush.txt");

            case 8:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file eight.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("ThreeKind.txt");

            case 9:
                Console.WriteLine(">Loading file nine.");
                return Path.GetFullPath("TwoPair.txt");

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid request.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you hit a case which the compiler doesn't understood right.

You are checking for errorCheck in a while loop and inside have a case. that case will always do a return, but as the compiler sees a probability that errorCheck got true without a return then it complains about the possibility of a execution path where no return exists.

First of all, you are doing a return in all the cases, so that  while can be safely removed as it does nothing. Else, if you plan to not return always and really loop until the user selects a correct option ignore errorCheck, just do a while(true){ ... } as your switch will return when a correct option is selected.

Comment: Yes, there was the incorret "!=", but it behaves as I explained even when corrected, so my answer is right, so the downvote is unfair as this answer is right

Comment: I'm not the one who has down-voted you, I'm not sure who that was.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, don't know who did it, but as i said this is really a misunderstanding of the compiler

Comment: Interesting to know why this answer got downvotes... It's not really compiler's fault that halting problem is so hard :)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, the compiler got to an infinite loop (there's no case where errorCheck got false without a return), so it's a compiler error

Answer (score 0):

An example written in VB, but it should show the logic.  My variable came from a database variable filled on the OnLoad event, but other than that, it's pretty much what you're looking to do.

```
Private Sub ShowPDF()

    Dim mySelection As Integer = _myDb.MyHuntingArea
    'the path where the pdf files are located
    Dim filePath As String = MyMachine.AssemblyDirectory & "\Regulations\"
    'variable for the appropriate file name to get
    Dim fileName As String = ""
    Select Case mySelection

        Case 1 
            fileName = filePath & "Area1.pdf"
        Case 2 
            fileName = filePath & "Area2.pdf"
        Case 3  
            fileName = filePath & "Area3.pdf"
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("We cannot determine what area you are requesting regulations for.  Make sure it is set under Setup.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Select

    If Not fileName = "" Then
        Try
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```